# selection box around button tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using python3 on windows and tkinter for visual.
I'm using ttk from tkinter for my widgets, unfortunately each time I'm clicking one of the widgets a selection box is appearing around it like when pressing 'Tab'.

Before clicking on it:

[image: before clicking on it]

After clicking on it:

[image: after clicking on it]

I want this selection box not to appear each time I'm clicking one of the widgets. In addition, I would like that, each time I click on a button, a blue border appears around it to show I have clicked it and  disappears when clicking on a different widget

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear, can you edit it

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example and make your question a bit clearer?

Comment: hey, I made my question more clear I hope(: thanks!

Comment: Try `takefocus = 0` during object declaration.

Comment: thanks, it is working but just on the same window, when im clicking a button that opening a different window the takefocus=0 dosent work on him, in additional I would like to make a blue selection box around a button to indicate that i clicked it

Comment: You need to apply it to all widgets (Buttons) in this case.

Comment: I just applied it to every widget I have even labels and it still didn't work

Comment: I do not think `takefocus` will allow you to focus back to the widget at all @Derek

Comment: Yes it's very specific. I'll show you, give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Two rows of buttons, the first row takes no focus.

```py
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

for a in range( 5 ):
    b = tk.Button( master, takefocus = 0, text = f"button {a}" )
    b.grid( row = 0, column = a, sticky = "nsew" )

for a in range( 5 ):
    b = tk.Button( master, text = f"button {a}" )
    b.grid( row = 1, column = a, sticky = "nsew" )
b.focus()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: why are you importing `threading`? and you could have simplified your answer with like max 3 lines of code (just to show how to add the attribute)

Comment: Yes it has no purpose, that's what happens when taking code from existing files in a hurry.@Matiss